# HyperlinkEvent with wrapLongStringIntoMultiLine on JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane

I have a content that include a hyperlink. This content can be change by author. I use StringUtil.wrapLongStringIntoMultiLine to set length of content. In this case, I have a issue : the end length of line random in the scope of hyperlink, so the structure of hyperlink is broken. The text show on dialog is not expect.
Here is my code :

```
 String language=" Deutsch, English (All), English (United Kingdom),Deutsch, English (All), English (United Kingdom), Bahasa Indonesia,Italiano <a href=\"\">  edit</a>  ";
        JLabel lblCompleDescr = new JLabel();
        lblCompleDescr.setFont((new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12)));
        language=StringUtil.wrapLongStringIntoMultiLine(language, 68);
```

In the special case, the language variable will look like :

```
<html> Deutsch, English (All), English (United Kingdom),Deutsch, English <br/>(All), English (United Kingdom), Bahasa Indonesia,Italiano <a <br/>href="">  edit</a>  </html>
```

The structure of hyperlink is broke. Please give me advise to fix issue. thanks

Comment: What is the StringUtil.wrapLongStringIntoMultiLine? Why do you need it to wrap this way? JEditorPane with HTMLEditorKit provides line wrap.

Comment: @StanislavL: I want to set width and height of Jedittor by using wrapLongStringIntoMultiLine. The language variable can be changed by author, so I dont set by setPreferredSize() by specific value.

Comment: You can fix width and calculate height http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html for the width